# Efficient algorithm to construct path augmented graphs with smallest diameter?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am interested in special graph constructions that have the smallest diameter. We have a path graph $P_n$ ($N$ is even). We add new set of edges $C$ between path nodes such that set $C$ forms a perfect matching. The output graph is the union of path $P_n$ and perfect matching $C$ on the path nodes.

> What is the fastest deterministic algorithm that produces graphs with the smallest possible diameter if the input is $P_n$ path?

I suspect that the problem has intermediate complexity (neither in $P$ nor in NP-complete).

This was motivated by this [post on CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37837/add-a-matching-to-a-hamiltonian-path-to-reduce-the-max-distance-between-given-pa).

P.S. I also posted on [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218929/path-augmentation-to-minimize-the-diameter) which asks for the diameter of a greedy construction.

Comment: Based on the other post, I believe this formulation is ambiguous.  You should specify what the output graph is (path union matching, I'm guessing).  Right now as stated, the answer is a complete graph.  Gerhard "Often Goes For Easy Answer" Paseman, 2017.04.07.

Comment: It looks like the output graph has all vertices of degree at most 3. Starting from a point and counting left right turns, the smallest the diameter can be is Omega(log n). Likely a divide and conquer greedy algorithm can give a near optimal solution when the input is a path.  Gerhard "Does Being Greedy Help Here?" Paseman, 2017.04.07.

Comment: Also interesting if the input graph is a cycle $C_n$ on $N$ nodes.

Comment: As you state it, the algorithm has exponential time.  The input size is the number of bits in the integer $n$, while the output size is $\Omega(n)$ times larger.  $n\log n$ is an exponential function of $\log n$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. N is not part of the input. The input is a path $P_n$.

Comment: It is similar to the problem of finding a subcubic graph of minimum diameter.  There are bounds and some constructions for small size but no general solution known. My prediction is that the only missing link is theory. One day a good graph theorist will devise a general optimal construction that will be routine to carry out. In other words, my feeling is that no complexity other than P is likely but we don't yet have the tools to prove it.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thank you for you comment. Is the situation similar if the input graph is Hamiltonian cycle $C_n$?

Comment: I guess so, but I don't see any chance of a proof anytime soon.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I would be grateful if you could share some reference to the problem of finding a subcubic graph of minimum diameter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Victor  See http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree/Diameter_Problem  .